# is the existence of a coarsest topology nontrivial

Tags: general-topology

I understand what the [definition](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3812408/coarsest-topology) of "the coarsest topology satisfying some property x" is, but my question is, shouldn't the existence of such a topology be nontrivial?

For example, let $X = \{ a, b, c \}$, and let our property be "has four elements". Then since $\{ \emptyset, \{a\}, \{b, c\}, \{a, b, c\} \}$ and $\{ \emptyset, \{c\}, \{a, b\}, \{a, b, c\} \}$ are both four element topologies on $X$, there can not be a coarsest topology.

I am asking this because many problems from my homework refer to a coarsest topology, and I just want to verify that the existence of one is indeed nontrivial.

Answer (score 4):

As you correctly observed, triviality depends on "property x". The properties that work "trivially" are precisely(?) those where the intersection of arbitrarily many topologies with property x is again a topology with  property x.

Perhaps there are a few semi-trivial cases, where that intersection only *contains* a possibly coarser topology with property x? At last, that's the most general case that even allows us to speak of *the* coarsest topology among the partially ordered (by inclusion / coarserness) set of topologies with property $x$.

Comment: Right, partially ordered sets need not have a least element. Thanks, this makes sense.